# Second row entry width affect the first row style in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]I'm trying to create the some sample application.

Which first row is One label then input entry box then submit button.
Then second row has the another entry box.

My problem is when I increase width of the entry box in second row it affect the first row style. I don't know what is the problem.

```
import Tkinter
tk_obj = Tkinter.Tk()
tk_geo = tk_obj.geometry("1200x800")
Tkinter.Label(tk_obj, text='Enter query ').grid(row=1,column=1)

def callback():
    print "hi"


E1 = Tkinter.Entry(tk_obj,bd=3,width=120)
E1.grid(row=1, column=2,ipady=3)

b = Tkinter.Button(tk_obj, text="Check", command=callback)
b.grid(row=1,column=3)

E2 = Tkinter.Entry(tk_obj,bd=3,width=100)
E2.grid(row=2,column=1,ipady=100)



tk_obj.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first elements of the first and second rows are in the same column. They can't be anything other than the same width. If you want a different layout, please describe the exact appearance you're trying to achieve (with an image if necessary).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I added image

Comment: Ah, you want that widget to spill into the second column. Have you tried the `columnspan` setting, with `E2.grid(row=2,column=1,ipady=100, columnspan=2)`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Ya I tried. But It doesn't work. I'm trying to align the second row grid in bottom of the `Entry query` label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grid` method places widgets in the center of the cell they inhabit. When you have two widgets of different sizes sharing a row or column, this means that there will be blank space around the smaller widget. To make the second `Entry` widget span the first two columns, use `columnspan=2` when you `grid()` it. To left-align it within those two columns, use `sticky='W'`:

```
E2.grid(row=2,column=1,ipady=100, columnspan=2, sticky='W')
```

You can then adjust that `Entry` widget's `width` attribute until it looks the way you want it to.

Comment: Thank you It is working. But I can't understand what is actual going here.